# Pass vector as a chain of strings R

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
vectr <- c("LIBDISP1","LIBDISP2","LIBDISP3")
```

and I want it as a chain of strings to use in a sql query.

```
"'LIBDISP1','LIBDISP2','LIBDISP3'"
```

I tried the following:

```
text <- paste(as.character(vectr), collapse = ", ")
```

But it returns:

```
"LIBDISP1, LIBDISP2, LIBDISP3"
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sQuote` with `paste`

```
paste(sQuote(vectr, FALSE), collapse=', ')
#[1] "'LIBDISP1', 'LIBDISP2', 'LIBDISP3'"
```

or with `toString`

```
toString(sQuote(vectr, FALSE))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `paste0` like :

```
paste0("'", vectr, "'", collapse = ",")
#[1] "'LIBDISP1', 'LIBDISP2', 'LIBDISP3'"
```